# Display all latitude and longitude once in a MAP

Tags: r, google-maps

I have a dataset like

```
latitude    longitude   Class   prediction
9.7          21.757     244732     1
12.21        36.736     112206     0
-15.966      126.844    133969     1
```

Now i am trying to group all '1' at prediction column and take their latitude and longitude, later i want to display the all points on a single map.

Actually the code i wrote its takes each '1' on prediction column and takes lat and long respectively and display one point on map each time. But I want to collect all lat and long where prediction is 1 and display all points on a  one map.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap) #install.packages("ggmap")

#data set name testData1
for (i in  1:100){

  if (testData1$prediction[i]==1) {

    lat <- testData1$latitude[i]
    lon <- testData1$longitude[i]
    df <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon,lat))

    # getting the map
    mapgilbert <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(df$lon), lat = mean(df$lat)), zoom = 4,
                          maptype = "satellite", scale = 2)

    # plotting the map with some points on it
    ggmap(mapgilbert) +
      geom_point(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = "red", alpha = 0.8), size = 5, shape = 21) +
      guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE, size=FALSE)

  }

}
```

Comment: normally i will get answers in a 5 min. its been a hour . .wht hpnd to active users ! please help

Comment: you've asked a total of 3 questions (incl this one) on SO. Hardly enough to build an accurate predictive model on speed of answering.

Comment: Sample size is too low to predict ! . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things. You could simply subset `df` like so:

```
ggmap(mapgilbert) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df, prediction == 1), aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = "red", alpha = 0.8), size = 5, shape = 21) +
  guides(fill = FALSE, alpha = FALSE, size = FALSE)
```

Comment: I created a df , where V1 = lat, V2 = long, V3=Prediction . I changed piece of code. It subset the data perfect. But i could not see any points on map. All i see is only map. No coordinates on Map                                                                             ggmap(mapgilbert) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df, V3 == 2), aes(x = V1, y = V2, fill = "red", alpha = 0.8), size = 9, shape = 21) +
  guides(fill = FALSE, alpha = FALSE, size = FALSE)

Comment: Compare the limits of the map with the coordinates you want to see, maybe they are out of the range of the displayed map.